# AngularJS directive is not generating list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

when I run my code

```
 <div>Floor:  {{Floors.FloorName}}  </div>
```

in the source in browser I get:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="FloorCntl">

    <!--

    ngRepeat: Floors in Floors

    -->
```

it gets commented out 
code is on [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbwilly/gkXQ5/embedded/result/)

Comment: Please share the controller script code

Comment: Why do you have `Floors.$scope = `? Did you mean `$scope.Floors = `?

Comment: Fixed several things, got it working: http://jsfiddle.net/w4wqB/ - including the `ng-model`/`ng-click` having empty or invalid values (too many single quotes)...adding `ng-app` to a container div...changing `Floors.$scope` to `$scope.Floors` in your JS...changing the `ng-repeat` to be `ng-repeat="Floor in Floors"`...(and added bootstrap/jQuery libraries for fun)

Comment: you and right it is now working in jsfiddle however I make the same changes in VS2013 and It is not showing the {{Floor.FloorName}} from angurlarJS ... do you have any ideas. thanks for your help on the issue on $scope and other changes that fixed it in jsfiddle.

Comment: in  vs2013 I am getting some javascript errors out of the angular.min.js code in line line 20 column 254, line 151 column 401

Answer (score 0):

I just updated your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gkXQ5/2/

You didn't add ng-app in the page

```
<div ng-app class="col-lg-4" >
    <h3>Floor Request</h3>
    <div ng-controller="FloorCntl">
        <div ng-repeat="Floor in Floors">
            <div>Floor:  {{Floor.FloorName}}  </div>

        </div>

    </div>  
</div>
```